# Connecting the dots

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations

Given two sets of $n$ and $m$ vertices with $m > n$ how can we count the number of bipartite graphs with $m \leq k \leq m \cdot n$ edges where every vertex is connected? E.g. for $n=2$ and $m=k=3$ there are six configurations:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post it here:<br/>
Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796507/counting-bipartite-graphs

Comment: [This question is related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796507/counting-bipartite-graphs) (linked question is about counting the same flavor of bipartite graph, but without specifying the number of edges, $k$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with inclusion-exclusion. There are $nm$ edges possible. You want to choose $k$ edges such that no vertex is isolated. Say you pick edges such that $i$ of the $n$ vertices on one side are isolated, and $j$ of the $m$ vertices on the other side are isolated. Then there are $\binom{(n-i)(m-j)}{k}$ ways to choose your edges. There are $\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{j}$ ways to pick which vertices are isolated. Using the principle of inclusion-exclusion, the number of ways to pick your edges is $$\sum_{0\leq i<n,\; 0\leq j<m} (-1)^{i+j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{m}{j}\binom{(n-i)(m-j)}{k}$$ and that's the number of graphs possible.

It's worth noting that the factor $\binom{(n-i)(m-j)}{k}$ will often be $0$, so you can specify in the sum that you only care about $i$ and $j$ such that $\binom{(n-i)(m-j)}{k}>0$. This is why we don't need to consider the case that $i=n$ or $j=m$.

In your example, we look at the sum $$\sum_{0< i< 2,\; 0<j< 3} (-1)^{i+j}\binom{2}{i}\binom{3}{j}\binom{(2-i)(3-j)}{3}$$ where the only values of $(i,j)$ where the last binomial coefficient is nonzero are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$. The sum above then simplifies to $$(-1)^{0}\binom{2}{0}\binom{3}{0}\binom{6}{3}+(-1)^1\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{3}+(-1)^1\binom{2}{0}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{3}=\\
20-2-12=6,$$ the answer that you found.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you used inclusion-eyclusion?

Comment: @Christian One way to view inclusion-exclusion is to view it as avoiding certain properties. In this case, for each vertex $v$, we can let $p_v$ be the property that vertex $v$ is isolated. Then we want to count the number of bipartite graphs that avoid the property $p_v$ for all $v\in V(G)$. Inclusion-exclusion tells you that you can count the number of graphs that have no isolated vertices by expressing it as a sum of the numbers of graphs that have some isolated vertices. In this problem, counting the number of graphs only depends on how many vertices in each part are isolated. (1)

Comment: @Christian (See section 2 of http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/resources/inclusion_exclusion.pdf for more detail.) Let $f(i,j)$ denote the number of bipartite graphs where *exactly* $i$ vertices from the size-$n$ part are isolated, and *exactly* $j$ vertices from the size-$m$ part are isolated. We want to compute $f(0,0)$. If you replace *exactly* above with *at least*, we'll denote that $g(i,j)$. Then $\sum_{i\geq a, j\geq b} f(i,j)=g(a,b)$. (2)

Comment: @Christian Inclusion-exclusion then tells us that $f(0,0)=\sum_{i\geq 0, j\geq 0} (-1)^{i+j} {n \choose i}{m\choose j}g(i,j)$. The ${n\choose i}$ and ${m\choose j}$ come from choosing which vertices are isolated. You can then check that $g(i,j)=\binom{(n-i)(m-j)}{k}$. (3)

Comment: Thank you very much!